# shared library (PIC) returns a pointer to caller results SEGFAULT

Tags: c, linux, pointers, shared-libraries

I've built a shared library using gcc on Linux (test.so)
the code of course is PIC.

one of test.so API calls returns a pointer to a struct on the shared library stack and another call
returns a pointer to a struct on the shared library data segment.

When I am trying to access these pointesr after getting them from the shared library I get a SEGFAULT.

My questions are these:

1. stack addresses should always be valid (as they are calculated as offests to SP) so why did i get a SEGFAULT?
2. for global addresses, if I access them inside the library the compiler uses a base value given by the dynamic loader to resolve them, but what happens if i do this:

   return &x

does the compiler returns the resolved address or does it assume because no LOAD/STORE was executed it can remain the non resolved address?

if it does not resolve the address then the caller might get an offset address instead of a valid address. is this possible?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

> one of test.so API calls returns a pointer to a struct on the shared library stack

There is *no such thing* as the "shared library stack". There is only one stack (for each thread), and returning an address of a local variable is almost never what you want.

> another call returns a pointer to a struct on the shared library data segment.

That's ok, so long as you don't `dlclose()` the library in question.

> When I am trying to access these pointesr after getting them from the shared library I get a SEGFAULT.

It is likely that you didn't tell us the whole story, and that your problem is elsewhere.

In any case, given the information you provided a good answer is unlikely. Please edit your question with more details. A test case that can be built and that demonstrates your problem is best.